# Listen Stream with StreamProvider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm coding function Add to Shoppingcard in app buy books-example.

1. I have an API /count to get total of products users add to shoppingcard
2. an API /list is list of products in shoppingcard, this list running correctly
3. According to BLoC architecture, I have an shoppingcardStream and shoppingcardSink
   When user click "buy", I add event "addToCard" stream, shoppingcardStream will listen that event, and Sink new event to UI page, with StreamProvider, I get value.total (number of products) and show to user.
   My problem: when click "buy", total return -1, in stead of +1 by logic, I check that is my default value if get API return null(picture 1)
   If I rebuild app, total is correct value, I don't know why this bug is occur and how to fix it, help me please, I have delayed it 5 days :((
   Many thanks.
   [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESZck.png)
   [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHHox.png)

THIS IS CLASS TO SHOW 'total'

```
class CartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartWidgetState createState() => _CartWidgetState();
}

class _CartWidgetState extends State<CartWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    var bloc = Provider.of<HomeBloc>(context);
    bloc.getShoppingCartInfo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<HomeBloc>(
      builder: (context, bloc, child) {
        return StreamProvider<ShoppingCart?>.value(
          initialData: null,
          value: bloc.shoppingCartStream,
          catchError: (context, error) {
            return ShoppingCart(total: -1);
          },
          child: Consumer<ShoppingCart?>(
            builder: (context, value, child) {
              if (value == null) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 20),
                  child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                );
              }
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/checkout");
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 20),
                  child: badges.Badge(
                    badgeContent: Text(
                      "${value.total}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

THIS IS MY BLoC

```
  final _shoppingCardSubject = BehaviorSubject<ShoppingCart>();
  Stream<ShoppingCart> get shoppingCartStream => _shoppingCardSubject.stream;
  Sink<ShoppingCart> get shoppingCartSink => _shoppingCardSubject.sink;

  @override
  void dispatchEvent(BaseEvent event) {
    switch (event.runtimeType) {
      case AddToCartEvent:
        handleAddToCart(event);
        break;
    }
  }

  handleAddToCart(event) {
    AddToCartEvent addToCartEvent = event as AddToCartEvent;
    _orderRepo.addToCart(addToCartEvent.bookData).then((shoppingCart) {
      shoppingCartSink.add(shoppingCart);
    });
  }

  getShoppingCartInfo() {
    Stream<ShoppingCart>.fromFuture(_orderRepo.getShoppingCartInfo()).listen(
        (shoppingCart) {
      _shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
      shoppingCartSink.add(shoppingCart);
    }, onError: (err) {
      _shoppingCardSubject.addError(err);
    });
  }
```

THIS IS CLASS TO GET "total" from backend, and it return -1 when i click "buy"

```
class ShoppingCart {
  int total;

  ShoppingCart({required this.total});

  factory ShoppingCart.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ShoppingCart(
        total: json["data"] ?? -1,
      );
}
```

I tried to find why null is returned, but i don't understand, I'm exepecting that total will add 1 when i click "buy"